# Passing a (uint8) NumPy array from python to c++ using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, bind, wrapper, ctypes

I have managed to make it work for double NumPy values but for uint8 i get no print output.

C++ file *foo.cpp* (simple iterates over the array):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void cfoo(const uint8_t *indatav, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
        cout << "c++ vals --> " << indatav[i + cols * j] << '\n';
      }
    }
}
```

Make it a shared library :

```
gcc -lstdc++ -shared -o foo.so foo.cpp
```

(Bind) Python script (pass NumPy array to C++):

```
import ctypes
import numpy.ctypeslib as ctl
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./foo.so")
cfoo = lib.cfoo
cfoo.restype = None
cfoo.argtypes = [ctl.ndpointer(np.uint8, flags='aligned, c_contiguous'), ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

# Initialize np.array    
pyvals = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype=np.uint8)
print "pyvals type : ",pyvals.dtype

for i in range (0,pyvals.shape[0]):
    for j in range (0, pyvals.shape[1]):
        print "python vals", pyvals[i,j]

# Call c++ function 
cfoo(pyvals , pyvals.shape[0], pyvals.shape[1])
```

Output (I can see no print in cout ... ) :

```
pyvals type :  uint8
python vals 1
python vals 2
python vals 3
python vals 4
c++ vals -->
c++ vals -->
c++ vals -->
c++ vals -->
```

However, when I change `dtype=np.uint8` to `dtype=np.double` and `const uint8_t *indatav` to `const double *indatav` I get the correct results :

```
indata type :  float64
python vals 1.0
python vals 2.0
python vals 3.0
python vals 4.0
c++ vals --> 1
c++ vals --> 3
c++ vals --> 2
c++ vals --> 4
```

What change should I make for uint8 numpy.ndarray to work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

I had to cast the array to unsigned int, since ostream&operator<<(ostream&, unsigned char) is printing the characters and not decimals. According to the ASCII table values below 32 are not representing characters and that is the reason I couldn't see anything in the output.

Changing `indatav[i + cols * j]` to `static_cast<unsigned int>(indatav[i + cols * j])` solved the problem !

Thanks!